# Should I use UNION or something else for selecting data from multiple tables?

Tags: php, mysql, select, union

I have two tables in my mysql database: *female* and *male*. They both have 3 columns each: *id*, *name* and *age*.
I want a html table to be displayed with both table's data in it.

I have these code pieces:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM female ORDER BY age DESC LIMIT 20");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
  $age = $row['age'];
  $name = $row['name'];
}
```

and

```
$result01 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM male ORDER BY age DESC LIMIT 20");
while($row01 = mysql_fetch_array($result01))
{
  $age01 = $row01['age'];
  $name01 = $row01['name'];
}
```

So how should I mix these tables (the data)? Should I use the mysql `UNION` function or something else? What is the appropriate code for this job?

Thanks...

Comment: You've answered your own question! `UNION` is fine - were you after usage examples?

Comment: Unless those tables are radically different in structure, it'd be FAR easier to have a single table with an extra "sex" field that specifies "m" or "f".

Answer (score 3):

You should use

```
SELECT * FROM female ORDER BY age DESC LIMIT 20
UNION
SELECT * FROM male ORDER BY age DESC LIMIT 20
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM
    (SELECT * FROM female
     UNION
     SELECT * FROM male)
ORDER BY age DESC LIMIT 20
```

Finally, a consideration: why do you use separate tables for males and females? You caould use a single table with a column for sex...

Answer (score 1):

Well, the most appropriate solution is to not have separate `male` and `female` tables, but rather to have one `people` table with a `gender` column. That way, you don't have to go messing around with unionizing tables and going crazy to merge them when, really, all these rows belong in the same table. After all, if you're really all that interested in selecting only male or female people, that's what `WHERE` is for.

But if this is a legacy database with the schema set in stone, I feel your pain, and [Marco's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8001270/should-i-use-union-or-something-else-for-selecting-data-from-multiple-tables/8001296#8001296) would do the trick :)

Comment: I was bringing these tables as an example... just an example. My code is a lot more complicated :P

Comment: Aha, that makes much more sense :D Glad to hear it.